# Flutter: Notification icon showing white circle

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification

I have tried everything including changes in manifest file as well as putting the icon property in notification function but the notification icon is still white circle! My icons color is white with transparent background which is generated using https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit.

My manifest file looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtktH.png)

```
         <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
         android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />

         <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

I have included the picture of my folder structure! What exactly am I missing?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVN7M.png)

Comment: As far as I know, if your icon is still a white circle then the background is not transparent. Also, I assume the icon is a png image? I have had complete success using this site to turn my pngs into icons with transparent backgrounds. https://onlinepngtools.com/create-transparent-png maybe try it?

Comment: @JideGuru It is transparent and I also used the site that you mentioned but still the result is same!

Comment: PS. Maybe show us the list of files in your drawable folder.

Comment: Is the name of your guaranteed-transparent icon 'notification_icon.png' and is it in the drawable folder under android/app/src/main/res? I know these seem like stupid questions but usually there are simple reasons for these problems.

Comment: PS jideGuru just edited your post. GrahamD is commenting.

Comment: @GrahamD, I just have notification_icon.png on my drawable folder. I can show you in the picture that it is a transparent image! The picture is updated above

Comment: Ok, I am afraid that I'm out of ideas. Hope that someone else can help you.

Comment: One last thought, what is the content of the notification payload that you are using to create the notification? It doesn't define an icon, does it?

Answer (score 3):

For those who arrive here lost, pay attention to the correct place where you must enter the meta-data

[image]

Comment: In 2024 this is still the way

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of a .png image in the res folder, try to download,unzip and paste all the drawable folders in the res folder.
   ie, drawable, drawable-hdpi etc.
   [image: drawable folders]
2. If you want to change the color of the icon,add the metadata tag after the notification icon tag

Go to "android\app\src\main\res\values" and add a colors.xml file
Inside it add the color:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#00FF00</color>
```

[image: colors.xml]

I had also come across this issue and have shared my solution on Github as well.
[flutter_notification_icon_issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941#issuecomment-622268132)

Incase, this doesn't work for you, I would suggest creating a different icon in Android Asset Studio using the existing clipart that they have provided and try that once. Just to make sure that the icon that you have created is not the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: '@mipmap/ic_notification_no_bg',
          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
        ),
      ));
```

You need to provide a icon which does not have any background in AndroidNotificationDetails so App will pick this icon for Android version 11 for other versions it will pick default launcher Icon

Answer (score 0):

For me answer given by @Marcos Silva worked. I also had correct icon, and was getting white circle in notification bar(for background notifications). When I moved meta tag right after `application` tag, it started showing icon correctly.